# how to use rank/join and where together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used multiple inner joins in my code, and I provided rank, but now I want to select a particular rank. So how to use rank in a where statement?

Here is my code, but now please help me to proceed further:

```
select [YEAR],
       [IDManufacturer],
       sum([TotalPrice]), 
       rank() over (order by sum(totalprice) desc) as sales_rank
       from [dbo].[DIM_DATE] 
       join [dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS] 
       on [dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS].Date = [dbo].[DIM_DATE].DATE
       join [dbo].[DIM_MODEL] 
       on [dbo].[DIM_MODEL].IDModel=[dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS].IDModel
       where [YEAR] in (2009,2010) 
       group by IDManufacturer,[year]
       order by sum([TotalPrice]) desc
```

Now I want to select only rank 3 and 4. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do `sub-query` or  `CTE`, i would suggest try with 2 methods and look at execution plan pick which performs better:

**Sub Query**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(select [YEAR],
       [IDManufacturer],
       sum([TotalPrice]) TotalPrice, 
       rank() over (order by sum(totalprice) desc) as sales_rank
from [dbo].[DIM_DATE] 
       join [dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS] 
       on [dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS].Date = [dbo].[DIM_DATE].DATE
       join [dbo].[DIM_MODEL] 
       on [dbo].[DIM_MODEL].IDModel=[dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS].IDModel
where [YEAR] in (2009,2010) 
       group by IDManufacturer,[year]
) as SQ
Where sales_rank = 3 or sales_rank = 4
go
```

**Common Table Expression**

```
; with CTE as

(select [YEAR],
       [IDManufacturer],
       sum([TotalPrice]) TotalPrice, 
       rank() over (order by sum(totalprice) desc) as sales_rank
from [dbo].[DIM_DATE] 
       join [dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS] 
       on [dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS].Date = [dbo].[DIM_DATE].DATE
       join [dbo].[DIM_MODEL] 
       on [dbo].[DIM_MODEL].IDModel=[dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS].IDModel
where [YEAR] in (2009,2010) 
       group by IDManufacturer,[year]
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE sales_rank = 3 or sales_rank = 4
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only rank 3 and 4 then try this:

```
   select * from (
   select [YEAR],
   [IDManufacturer],
   sum([TotalPrice]), 
   rank() over (order by sum(totalprice) desc) as sales_rank
   from [dbo].[DIM_DATE] 
   join [dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS] 
   on [dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS].Date = [dbo].[DIM_DATE].DATE
   join [dbo].[DIM_MODEL] 
   on [dbo].[DIM_MODEL].IDModel=[dbo].[FACT_TRANSACTIONS].IDModel
   where [YEAR] in (2009,2010) 
   group by IDManufacturer,[year]
   order by sum([TotalPrice]) desc
 ) t where sales_rank in (3,4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the 3rd and 4th values -- and assuming no ties -- then use `offset/fetch`:

```
offset 2 rows fetch first 2 rows only
```

The `offset 2` is because offset starts counting at `0` rather than `1`.